# Using local date format in the references in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, date, text-formatting, localization, bibliography

I write a paper with Microsoft Word and use the Harvard reference style. My problem is that at the reference section, Word formats the dates in US format, but the document is in my local language, so I would like to use the local date format.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE: example: [Hozzáférés dátuma: 10 7 2019].

Interestingly, the "access date" is in Hungarian, but the date is in an international(?) format

UPDATE2: I installed the Hungarian language pack for Microsoft Office and set Hungarian as the default language in File/Options/Language, still, it produces the above date format.

UPDATE3: I selected the system-wide date format for my taste following https://superuser.com/a/330792/216969 to no avail

UPDATE4: At the INSERT/Date button, I can select the date format and can make it default for Microsoft Word but this has no effect on the bibliography. Is this a bug then?

Comment: Harvard Reference dates are usually year only. What exactly is your issue? Can you [edit] and provide an example?

Comment: Added an example.